# MS Dos Cmd - Rename - adding a leading character to filename

Tags: cmd, rename

Having trouble getting the correct MSDOS command format. 
We need to add a leading zero to a batch of files in a directory on a regular basis. I cannot download and install a software item to do so.  The operating system is Windows-7. The length of the filenames varies.
i.e.

> 000165-CityName1.pdf to 0000165-CityName1.pdf
>   000166-CityNameLonger2.pdf to 0000166-CityNameLonger2.pdf
>   etc.

Looking for a rename command that would work, can someone please suggest one, it would be appreciated.  I have tried a half dozen without success.
Thank you
Russ

[image]

Comment: Might have a better chance of getting an answer at [su].

Comment: Questions about **general computing hardware and software** are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](http://superuser.com/tour).

Comment: Also, if you're using windows 7, you are *not* using MSDOS. The command prompt has been a separate thing (but visually similar, I'd agree) since ~Windows 98, IIRC. (On the Windows 9x line. On the Windows NT line, it was never MSDOS)

Comment: Please edit your question and post the contents of the `Rename-add1-from4-to-5-leading-0s.bat` file. It should include the six failing commands. REM the failing command lines out if you like.

Answer (score 3):

#### How do I add a leading zero to a batch of filenames?

Use the following command:

```
for /f %f in ('dir /b *.pdf') do ren "%f" "0%f"
```

To use in a batch file replace `%` with `%%`:

```
for /f %%f in ('dir /b *.pdf') do ren "%%f" "0%%f"
```

Example usage:

```
F:\test\test>dir
 Volume in drive F is Expansion
 Volume Serial Number is 3656-BB63

 Directory of F:\test\test

24/06/2016  21:39    <DIR>          .
24/06/2016  21:39    <DIR>          ..
24/06/2016  21:38                 0 000165-CityName1.pdf
24/06/2016  21:38                 0 000166-CityNameLonger2.pdf
               2 File(s)              0 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  1,769,011,425,280 bytes free

F:\test\test>for /f %f in ('dir /b *.pdf') do ren "%f" "0%f"

F:\test\test>ren "000165-CityName1.pdf" "0000165-CityName1.pdf"

F:\test\test>ren "000166-CityNameLonger2.pdf" "0000166-CityNameLonger2.pdf"

F:\test\test>dir
 Volume in drive F is Expansion
 Volume Serial Number is 3656-BB63

 Directory of F:\test\test

24/06/2016  21:40    <DIR>          .
24/06/2016  21:40    <DIR>          ..
24/06/2016  21:38                 0 0000165-CityName1.pdf
24/06/2016  21:38                 0 0000166-CityNameLonger2.pdf
               2 File(s)              0 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  1,769,011,425,280 bytes free
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [dir](http://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) - Display a list of files and subfolders.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.
- [ren](http://ss64.com/nt/ren.html) - Rename a file or files.

Comment: Nice! Thanks for this one!